# How to use structs for column names and values?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm playing around with Spark in Scala. I have this structure:

```
case class MovieRatings(movieName: String, rating: Double)
case class MovieCritics(name: String, movieRatings: List[MovieRatings])
```

The first class a movie and a rating given by some critic. It could be something like this:

```
MovieRatings("Logan", 1.5)
```

and a second class that accepts the name of the critic and a list of movies classified by him. With this I've come up with a List of MovieCritics and each element of the list has a name and a list of MovieRatings.
So far so good. Now I want to transform this List in a spark dataFrame to display the data in a more user friendly. Something like this:

```
Critic | Logan | Zoolander | John Wick | ...
Manuel    1.5       3            2.5
John      2         3.5          3
...
```

The firs column reflects the movie critic and the following columns represent the movie and the respective rating given by the critic.
My question is how to transform a

```
List(MovieCritics(name: String, movieRatings: List[MovieRatings]))
```

in that view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have data of movies as

```
val movieCritics = List(
  MovieCritics("Manual", List(MovieRatings("Logan", 1.5), MovieRatings("Zoolander", 3), MovieRatings("John Wick", 2.5))),
  MovieCritics("John", List(MovieRatings("Logan", 2), MovieRatings("Zoolander", 3.5), MovieRatings("John Wick", 3)))
)
```

You can create *dataframe* just by calling `toDF` as

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
val df = movieCritics.toDF
```

Which should be

```
+------+-----------------------------------------------+
|name  |movieRatings                                   |
+------+-----------------------------------------------+
|Manual|[[Logan,1.5], [Zoolander,3.0], [John Wick,2.5]]|
|John  |[[Logan,2.0], [Zoolander,3.5], [John Wick,3.0]]|
+------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Now simple `select` from above *dataframe* should get you the output you need

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.select(col("name"), col("movieRatings")(0)("rating").as("Logan"), col("movieRatings")(1)("rating").as("Zoolander"), col("movieRatings")(2)("rating").as("John Wick")).show(false)
```

This should result the final *dataframe* as

```
+------+-----+---------+---------+
|name  |Logan|Zoolander|John Wick|
+------+-----+---------+---------+
|Manual|1.5  |3.0      |2.5      |
|John  |2.0  |3.5      |3.0      |
+------+-----+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Beautiful!!! That's exactly what I was looking for. I was iterating lists in lists to transform the original data but I knew it was ugly and had to be some other way (I'm giving my first steps in scala and spark)

Comment: That's close but not the solution **I** would be looking for :) That assumes the number of columns for movies and their names. If that's the intent of the OP, fine, but thought it'd be too many assumptions. How about that challenge? I *am* close...

Comment: @Jaceb Laskowski, you're right but I'm doing small steps. Now I know how to transform the data. The next step will be how to do it if I have, say, 100 movies and I don't know a priori their names. A more dynamic thing. Anyway thanks for the help

Comment: See my answer which I think you may like. Took me over an hour (!)

Answer (score 1):

> how to transform `List(MovieCritics(name: String, movieRatings: List[MovieRatings]))`

That's as simple as using `toDS` on the `List`. That is only available when you have `SparkSession`'s [implicits](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@implicits) in scope which is (again) as simple as the following:

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import sparkSession.implicits._
```

If you work with `scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[MovieCritics]` or similar collection data structure you have to "map" it using `toSeq` or `toArray` before `toDS` to "escape" from Iterable. Implicits are not available for Iterables.

Given the list is `critics` you'd have to do the following:

```
critics.toDS
```

> Now I want to transform this List in a spark dataFrame to display the data in a more user friendly.

That's the most entertaining part of your question (took me a couple of hours to finally understand and write a solution). I'd appreciate comments to make it prettier.

```
case class MovieRatings(movieName: String, rating: Double)
case class MovieCritics(name: String, movieRatings: Seq[MovieRatings])
val movies_critics = Seq(
  MovieCritics("Manuel", Seq(MovieRatings("Logan", 1.5), MovieRatings("Zoolander", 3), MovieRatings("John Wick", 2.5))),
  MovieCritics("John", Seq(MovieRatings("Logan", 2), MovieRatings("Zoolander", 3.5), MovieRatings("John Wick", 3))))
```

With the input dataset set, here comes the solution.

```
val ratings = movies_critics.toDF
scala> ratings.show(false)
+------+-----------------------------------------------+
|name  |movieRatings                                   |
+------+-----------------------------------------------+
|Manuel|[[Logan,1.5], [Zoolander,3.0], [John Wick,2.5]]|
|John  |[[Logan,2.0], [Zoolander,3.5], [John Wick,3.0]]|
+------+-----------------------------------------------+

val ratingsCount = ratings.
  withColumn("size", size($"movieRatings")).
  select(max("size")).
  as[Int].
  head

val names_ratings = (0 until ratingsCount).
  foldLeft(ratings) { case (ds, counter) => ds.
    withColumn(s"name_$counter", $"movieRatings"(counter)("movieName")).
    withColumn(s"rating_$counter", $"movieRatings"(counter)("rating")) }

val movieColumns = names_ratings.
  columns.
  drop(1).
  filter(name => name.startsWith("name")).
  map(col)
val movieNames = names_ratings.select(movieColumns: _*).head.toSeq.map(_.toString)
val ratingNames = movieNames.indices.map(idx => s"rating_$idx")
val cols = movieNames.zip(ratingNames).map { case (movie, rn) =>
  col(rn) as movie
}
val solution = names_ratings.select(($"name" +: cols): _*)
scala> solution.show
+------+-----+---------+---------+
|  name|Logan|Zoolander|John Wick|
+------+-----+---------+---------+
|Manuel|  1.5|      3.0|      2.5|
|  John|  2.0|      3.5|      3.0|
+------+-----+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Very cool @JacekLaskowski, very cool indeed!! Thank you very much for the effort. Now it's my time to digest all this info. There's a lot of stuff going on. And, by the way, now my original question has a good title :)

Comment: @MLeiria I apologize for the very first unpleasant effect :) If you like it, approve. It took me some effort indeed. Hope to save some people's time. And yours too. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

```
ratings.selectExpr("name","explode(movieRatings) as mr").select("name", 
"mr.movieName", "mr.rating")
.groupBy("name")
.pivot("movieName")
.agg(first("rating"))
.show(10,false)
```